# Subgroup and Normal in Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Let $N$ be a subgroup of $Z(G)$. Show that $N$ is normal in G.

My Proof: $N\leq Z(G)$ (subgroup) and $Z(G)\leq G$ so $N\leq G$.
$\forall  h\in N$ we have $h\in Z(G)$ and this means $\forall g\in G$  we have  $gh=hg$ 
and   $gh$ for all $h\in N$ build up left coest $gN$ and similarly $hg$ for all $h\in N$ build up right coset $Ng$. Therefore, $\forall h\in N$ , $gh=hg$ . So, $\forall g\in G$ , $gN=Ng$ ,So $N\unlhd G$ .
Please look at my approach, is it correct and enough.

Comment: It's totally correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is  a correct proof.